# How to use ZLUDA for whisper?

Tags: gpu, intel, openai-api, whisper

i'm trying to use WHISPER from OPENAI with ZLUDA.
(to run whisper on intel GPU condition)

I've installed ZLUDA and GEEKBENCH6 already, and

https://hothardware.com/news/cuda-on-intel-gpus-zluda

above link is saying "run zluda_with -- geekbench5 --compute CUDA".

But, it doesn't work after i typed above command on powershell.

My question is

1. How to use ZLUDA in this case?
2. If ZLUDA is not available currently, is there any other way to run whisper
   in intel GPU condition?

Thank you for reading.